# proving that dimension of span of some linearly independent vectors reduces by atmost 1, after adding random vector v to all of them

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The actual question that I encountered is the following:

Let $V$ be a vector space and $v_1, \ldots, v_n \in V$ be linearly independent. Show that for any $u \in V$, the dimension of $\text{span}(v_1 + u, \ldots , v_n + u)$ is at least $n-1$.

Obviously, the dimension can only stay the same, or decrease, as we still have only $n$ vectors. I can immediately see that if $u$ is $-v_i$ (i = 1,2,..,n), then the dimension reduces by $1$.

What I am unable to prove is that the dimension can't reduce any further.

Comment: Hint with $n=5$ for notational ease: Assume not. WLoG, Write $V_4+u$ and $V_5+u$ as linear comb's of the first $3$. Solve one of those for $u$ and plug that into the other to eliminate $u$ and get $V_5$ as as a lin. comb. of $V_1$,...$V_4$.

Comment: Assuming that adding $u$ to $v_i$ (i=1,..,5) results in 2 vectors, say $v_4+u$ and $v_5+u$, to become linearly dependent on $v_1+u, v_2+u, v_3+u$. Then:
$\\ \sum_{k=1}^{4} c_k(v_k+u) = 0 \ where \ some \ c_k's \neq 0,$ $\therefore  u = (\sum_{k=1}^{4} c_kv_k)/-(\sum_{k=1}^{4} c_k)$.
substituting $u$ in $\sum_{k=1}^{3} t_k(v_k+u) + t_5(v_5+u)= 0\ where \ some\ t_k's \neq 0$....then what?

This is what you asked me to do right? I'm afraid I still dont see the proof :/

Comment: plug that formula for $u$ in, for $u$, in the last equation you wrote to ELIMINATE $u$ from it. You'll be a left with a dependence relation among the original 5 vectors.

Comment: okay, i did, and got a really long equation with lots of c's and t's.
even after simplifying the equation to the form of $\sum \alpha_i v_i$, i still cant see how i can conclude that atmost 1 vector becomes linearly dependent and not 2  :/  :(

Comment: You have a (long) equation which amounts to a dependence relation among V1 .... V5, contradicting their linear independence. All the gory details of the coefficients are not essential, all you need is that it's not a trivial relation -- which may be a little easier if you start by writing V4+u and V5+5 as combs of the first three rather than a lin combs being 0.

Comment: One last comment -- so you have an equation of the form a1 V1 + ... + a5 V5 = 0. By lin ind, a1 = a2 =a3= a4= a5 = 0. Find a contradiction in there!

Comment: thanks! got it now :)